# How can I vectorize with numpy this while + (2x for) nested loop?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to improve the processing speed of an algorithm I'm working on. Before trying to use the multiprocessing Pool and map to efficently distribute the workload on all CPU cores, I want to vectorize, if possibile, this loop.

Here an example.

```
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
w = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]
u = sorted(w, reverse=True)
i = 0
check = 0

while v[i] != v[-1]:
    if check == 0:
        for k in range(len(w)):
            if (v[i] < w[k] & v[i+1] >= w[k]) or (v[i] > w[k] & v[i+1] <= w[k]):
                do_somthing()
                check = 1
                break
    i = i+1
    if check == 1:
        for k in range(len(u)):
            if (v[i] <= u[k] & v[i-1] > u[k]) or (v[i] >= u[k] & v[i-1] < u[k]):
                do_something_else()
                check = 0
                break
    i = i+1
```

The arrays values in the example are completely random. V contains at least 2000 elements, while w size is always fixed.

Comment: Is `w` sorted, such that `u` and `w` are mirror images?

Comment: Yes, w is sorted lowest_value -> highest_value.

Comment: Why not make this a function that accepts `ndarray` `v` and `w` arguments. Then compile the function with `numba.jit`. For peculiar loop operations that can be made to have no reliance on native CPython data types, `numba.jit` is almost always your best bet, and is generally faster even than a vectorized numpy version, while allowing you to still express the algorithm in a way that is readable and doesn't need obfuscated vector operations.

Comment: I agree that the vectorized version suggested by Paul is harder to read compeared to my "noob" code, but I think that it's because of my coding skill. I have just a "general idea" of what numba is and in which cases it should be used. Can you provide some useful link?

I just need to place the @jit decorator before the function definition (def) to let the magic happen? Does numba.jit work with the vectorized solution proposed by Paul?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt. I observed that the conditions in the first and second `for` blocks are identical, only one loop picks the lowest `w` that satisfies it, the other picks the highest `w`.

Could you please check whether the follwing gives correct results?

```
import numpy as n

assert len(v) % 2 == 0
sg = w[-1] + 1 # create numbers that are safely out of range
sl = w[0] - 1  #

# in the original code, do_something is executed at most once for
# every pair of v depending on some conditions relating to w.
# the next lines find the smallest w that is still larger than v and
# similar things (in other words we are binning v with respect to w), 
# in a vectorised fashion, i.e. for all v in one go.
# using this info we can avoid the loop and for each pair of v just
# pick the first w if  any that would have left the two v through in
# the if inside the loop
# the difference between bin_inds_left and _right is whether the bins
# are l <= bin < r or l < bin <= r
bin_inds_left = np.digitize(v, w)
bin_inds_right = np.digitize(v, w, True)

# in your loops, various conditions are applied to v[i] and v[i+1]
# or similarly, in vectorised code this translates to slice offsets
# the two following lines create the logical masks corresponding to
# the conditions in the left and right halves of the if statement
# in the first loop (IIRC they are swapped in the second loop)
# these masks are True if there is any permissible w and otherwise 
# False
mask_l = bin_inds_left[1::2] > bin_inds_left[::2]
mask_r = bin_inds_right[1::2] < bin_inds_right[::2]

mask = mask_l | mask_r

# for each pair find the smallest w that satisfies the left condition
k1 = bin_inds_left[::2][mask]
k1[~mask_l[mask]] = sg # this marks places where there is no such w

# and in the right condition
k2 = bin_inds_right[1::2][mask]
k2[~mask_r[mask]] = sg

# since it is or gated the first (smaller) of the two w's wins
kminw = np.minimum(k1, k2)

# same for the second loop
k1 = bin_inds_left[1::2][mask]
k1[~mask_l[mask]] = sl

k2 = bin_inds_right[::2][mask]
k2[~mask_r[mask]] = sl

# but since u is upside-down compared to w and we do all caluclations
# in w coordinates we must take the maximum
# and in the very last step we translate to u coordinates
kminu = len(w) - 1 - np.maximum(k1, k2)

do_something(kminw, 2*np.where(mask)[0])
do_something_else(kminu, 1 + 2*np.where(mask)[0])
```

Explanation: we use `np.digitize` to find the indices smalles / largest `w` which satisfy the various inequalities in one go for all `v`. This gives a couple of masks which we combine to determine for which `v, w` pairs `do_something` and `do_something_else` need to be executed. The arguments in the two last lines are indices into w and v.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I am reworking from scratch the entire algorithm, so I still have to rewrite the do_something() and do_something_else() functions and a lot of other things. I'll let you know as soon as possibile, thanks again man!

Comment: I get two times the same "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". First time kminw = np.min(k1, k2), second time kminu = len(w) - 1 - np.max(k1, k2).

I'm reading the numpy documentation about the modules and functions that you used, but it's clear that I'm not as skilled as you're. Can you please provide row by row explanation or what your code does? Cause sincerely, I don't undestanrd almost anything about it. Thank you again.

Comment: Oops, used the wrong `max`, (there is `max` and `maximum`) sorry about that. I'll see what I can do about explaining better.